# Is there a way to turn off BeamSync of the mouse cursor in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mouse

The mouse cursor in Mac OS X has a lag to it that drives me crazy. I love everything else about the OS though so I'd like to solve this.

In an earlier attempt to get rid the lag, I used a couple of programs that changed the acceleration curve of the cursor movement. They sort of worked, but were really just masking the problem a bit. I then tried disabling BeamSync using Quartz Debug. It disabled BeamSync on every EXCEPT the mouse cursor. I know this because when I would drag a window around, the window move move ahead of the cursor. The window edges would tear, indicating they were in fact not waiting for the vertical sync. The fact that the mouse cursor lagged behind the dragged window means the cursor is still waiting for the vertical sync.

Does anyone know how to disable BeamSyncing of the mouse cursor?

Comment: I've been using Macs for years and have never noticed mouse cursor lag. What kind of lag are you talking about? Are you on a very old Mac or something?

Comment: The only people I know who notice it are people who game or have previously gamed in Windows. They notice right away that the mouse cursor has a longer delay than Windows. I am using a MacBook Pro from late 2010 with a Core i5 processor @ 2.4GHz with 8GB RAM

Comment: Are you using a wireless (Bluetooth) mouse on your Mac?

Comment: No, I am using a wired Razer mouse. It performs perfectly in Windows

Comment: Have you tried USB Overdrive? It might have a feature to fix the lag. Also, do you experience the same lag when using the built-in trackpad?

Comment: I did try USB Overdrive. It has settings for the sensitivity and the acceleration, but nothing for the vertical syncing of the mouse cursor. Good suggestion though!

Comment: There's no lag in OS X cursor, it's a different acceleration curve. Check the provided answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post helps confirm the problem: http://d43.me/blog/1205/the-cause-for-all-your-mac-os-x-mouse-annoyances/

The experimental tool to fix the lag issue is here (also linked from the blog post)
http://smoothmouse.com/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your question is actually how to make OS X mouse acceleration more like on PC. Good thing there is a [question for this](https://superuser.com/questions/5150/make-mac-os-x-mouse-acceleration-more-windows-like) at superuser.com! Good luck.

Comment: The lag is commonly confused with acceleration. I stated in my question that I have tested many acceleration adjustment apps and obviously they don't solve the lag problem.